# Automation Testing configuration for MEAN.io

Tags: node.js, testing, mean-stack, mean.io

I want to config my MEAN.io project with automation testing. what are the tools and dependencies required? how to setup the project?

Comment: I tried installing grunt and mocha still i can't get clear idea

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution for the above question. Check this http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication/2/02